# isomorphism of quotient groups

Tags: normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

If G1 and G2 are groups ,H1 and H2 are normal subgroups,and G1/H1 and G2/H2 are quotient groups, then Is this true:
If G1/H1 and G2/H2 ,and H1 and H2 are isomorph then G1 and G2 are isomorph too.
I need an example to show it's not true.
Thanks.

Comment: I removed the tag "algebraic groups."  For reference, an algebraic group is a special kind of algebraic variety, so the tag is generally not appropriate for questions about arbitrary groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could take $G_1=S_3$, $H_1=A_3$ where $S_3$ denotes permutation group on $\{1,2,3\}$ and $A_3$ the even permuations in $S_3$.

Next to that take $G_2=\mathbb Z_6$, and $H_2=\{\bar0,\bar2,\bar4\}$.

The subgroups and quotients all have prime order, hence are cyclic.

$\mathbb Z_6$ is abelian, but $S_3$ is not, so they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks! What about this one:if G2/H2 and G1/H1 ,and G1 and G2 are isomorph then H1 and H2 are isomorph too.Is this true or not?

Comment: That's not true either

Comment: Do you know any example?